# Transit visa for Munich

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, south-african-citizens

Do I need a visa on a South-African passport if in transit in Munich en route to St. Petersburg

Answer (score 1):

No, as this is a transit flight and your are not leaving the airport while your are in Munich.

Comment: a link perhaps, to back this up?

Comment: Well, http://www.germany-visa.org/airport-transit-visa/ doesn't list South Africa as a nationality that implies the necessity to have a transit visa in the Schengen area.

Comment: ...according to that page, the layover also has to be <12 hours.

Comment: That's correct but not the full explanation. Some people *do* need visas for transit, even if they don't intend to leave the airport. It's not the case anywhere in the Schengen area for SA citizens however.